# Can I use webpack's hot module reloading with sailsjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sails.js, webpack, webpack-hmr

I'm working on a project using [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) and [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/). I'd like to be able to use Webpack's [hot module replacement](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html) so I can edit my code and have it change on the browser instantly. However, it doesn't seem obvious how I can wire it all up.

I'd like to be able to use `$ sails lift` and have it all just work.

If this were a node.js project, I'd simply configure webpack to use `react-transform-hmr` and start `webpack-dev-server` from package.json (e.g. [as described here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/setting-up-webpack-for-react-and-hot-module-replacement)). But, this doesn't seem a very *sails-y* thing todo.

I see the module [webpack-hot-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-hot-middleware) purports to be able to, "add hot reloading into an existing server without `webpack-dev-server`." However, I'm not sure where's the appropriate place to add Express middleware configuration in Sails >0.10.

Can anybody recommend a good way to set this up?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, after some noodling around a good approach looks to be to use the old `customMiddleware` option of sails's `http` middleware configuration, but only for the development environment kept in `config/env/development.js`.

1) Install react and react-dom (if you haven't already):

```
$ npm install react react-dom --save
```

2) Install webpack, hot module reloading (& ES6) support for sails:

```
$ npm install sails-webpack babel-core babel-loader \
  babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties babel-plugin-syntax-decorators \
  babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread \
  babel-plugin-transform-class-properties \
  babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy \
  babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread \
  babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react \
  copy-webpack-plugin file-loader --save
```

3) Install react transforms and middleware for hot module reloading:

```
$ npm install babel-plugin-react-transform
  react-transform-catch-errors react-transform-hmr \
  webpack-dev-middleware webpack-hot-middleware --save-dev
```

4) Disable the built-in grunt hook that would normally link your application:

```
// .sailsrc 
{
  "hooks": {
    "grunt": false
  }
}
```

5) Configure sails webpack configuration:

```
// config/webpack.js

var webpack = require('webpack');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

// compile js assets into a single bundle file
module.exports.webpack = {
  options: {
    context: path.join(__dirname, '..'),

    devtool: 'eval',

    entry: [
      './assets/js',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
    ],

    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.tmp/public'),
      publicPath: "/",
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

      /* Copy sails.io.js unmolested: */
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          from: 'assets/js/dependencies',
          to: 'dependencies',
          force: true
        }
      ]),
    ],

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },

    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(bower_components|node_modules)/,
          loader: 'babel',
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
        {
          test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.wav$|\.mp3$/,
          loader: "file" }
      ]
    }
  },

  // docs: https://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html#compiler
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300
  }
};
```

6) Configure project-wide `.babelrc` to use hot module reload in development mode:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-class-properties",
    "syntax-decorators",
    "syntax-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [["react-transform", {
        "transforms": [{
          "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
          "imports": ["react"],
          "locals": ["module"]
        }]
      }]]
    }
  }
}
```

7) Lastly, add `http.customMiddleware` configuration to sails's `config/env/development.js`:

```
module.exports = {

  /* ... */

  /*
   * Enable webpack hotloading while in development mode:
   */

  http: {
    customMiddleware: function (app) {
      var webpack = require('webpack');
      var webpackConfig = require('../webpack').webpack.options;
      var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

      app.use(require("webpack-dev-middleware")(compiler,
        {
          noInfo: true,
          publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
        }
      ));
      app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler,
        { reload: true }
      ));
    },
  }

  /* ... */
};
```

Presuming you've got a react application in `assets/js/index.jsx` (or similar) and a view which includes your `bundle.js` file you should be able to simply `$ sails lift` and see the following on your brower's development console:

```
  |>    Now connected to Sails.
\___/   For help, see: http://bit.ly/1DmTvgK
        (using browser SDK @v0.11.0)



client.js:51 [HMR] connected
```

And *boom* you should be in business!

Comment: I am the author of sails-webpack. Keep in mind that support for this module is ending: https://github.com/balderdash-projects/sails-webpack/issues/2

Comment: Also bear in mind that the instructions for sails-webpack indicate disabling of the grunt hook entirely.  If you do go with sails-webpack, you may need to find another way to do what the grunt hook provided through the default tasks (all the asset pipeline stuff like clean, uglify, copy, etc.).  I'm currently playing with just adding grunt-webpack into the out-of-the-box mix (haven't quite got it yet).  Maybe webpack can include all of that - I haven't familiarized myself with it yet.

Comment: Looks good, it's working! But what kind of code should to add to compile stylus to css? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution should work great but I wanted to drop in another quick solution for others reading this:

You can completely remove the Sails.js build pipeline and run webpack separately. Running both commands simultaneously in a subshell should do the trick.

`( webpack & sails lift ; )`

Both commands will run and you will see the output of both merged in the terminal. Ctrl+C will kill both correctly as well since it's running in a subshell.

You could create an npm script to save yourself from writing out the two commands each time.

Answer (score 1):

We created our own Sails hook to handle Webpack internally, works great at the moment. The config needs some cleaning however: https://github.com/teamfa/sails-hook-webpack